# What kind of light bulb fitting is this?

Tags: fitting, light-bulb

I have a ceiling light in my apartment which hasn’t had a bulb fitted in the last three years. I can’t for the life of me figure out what kind of fitting this is.

It has one main rectangular fitting, and three circular inserts on either side.

[image: light bulb fitting]

What kind of light bulb fitting is this? If it helps narrow it down, this is in the U.K.

Comment: Is it possible that the fixture is missing a piece?

Comment: This looks like a base for a multipin fluorescent lamp. That said, I've seen similar designs for four-pin lamps, but never for six pins. Perhaps it's designed to accommodate different types of four-pin lamps with different spacing between pins? This is just a guess... look at another lamp and see what's inside.

Comment: Looks like a multi-application socket, which pins connected determine function. Can you read the wattage of the transformer? https://www.lightsearch.com/images_site/lg_cflbase.gif

Comment: Are there any brand/model markings you can see anywhere?

Comment: I agree with Dr lots of compact fluorescents out there but 2 or 4 pin is the norm is there a cover to provide a possible shape?